# How to solve slow scrolling in QT android app

Tags: c++, performance, qt, opengl, scroll

I am trying to make a simple QT android app, but basically my problem is that on my main screen I have about 250 little images that i want to scroll. But I really need the scrolling to be fluent and fast. First I tried it using QML but it wasnt really fast, then I tried to make the app in qt designer and use widgets but that was very slow. Then I tried using openGL but on android I can only use openGL ES and I cant find so much examples because every example that I find is much more advanced than I need.

But basically my main question is, what do you think is the best way to solve my problem and if its openGL which way of using it is the best that could solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Neither approach should have problems when scrolling when compared to a native application on the same device. Check the following:

1. Make sure to measure performance only in release-builds, with QML debugging disabled and no debugger attached.
2. Maybe your device simply can't keep up with so many images in one view - then it's not a Qt problem. Compare with a 'native' java-App to see if this is the case.
3. Check if you implemented everything correctly; e.g. check if theres anything running in your main-loop or some events happenening repeatedly which consumes CPU time

And some more general advice:

1. Downscale your images to the appropriate view-size before giving them to the UI, as they might have to be re-scaled on every frame-update and/or consume graphics memory otherwise. E.g. dont set the source to a 1024x1024 image when it's going to show in a 64x64 view
2. Remove transparency from the images if they are going to display on solid-colored background anyway.
3. Dont overlay the images with other widgets/controls
4. If you're still getting a 'slow' UI, maybe try to merge all or multiple images and their surrounding UI/Controls into one or more bigger images
5. Very long views are not user-friendly. Maybe implement a pager or tab-view etc. to divide your list into multiple views. This way you can also decrease load-time
6. Dont try to implement an interface in openGL yourself. It's unlikely you'll  make a better one than you already get with QtWidgets and QtQuick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, ...

I always test in release builds, I tried it on multiple devices even on ios but its not perfect anywhere. My implementation is 100% correct. Mostly I test the scrolling in my side program only for this problem, so there is nothing else than screen with images. They are really downscaled and they have really slow size. The second thing is that i need to use the images as objects with labels and user should be able to click them, so they are not only images. I am really desperate now :/